# How did the magicians obtain the buttons that they possessed at the climax of "The Magician's Land"

Tags: the-magicians, lev-grossman

The Magicians trilogy features *magical buttons* that was used to travel between Earth/Fillory and the Neitherlands (presumably inspired by the similar magic rings featured in the Magician's Nephew).  Towards the end of the novel the text indicates that the magicians possess at least three such buttons.  But based on the earlier books I cannot see how they can have any of them.

Spoilers for all three books below.

In the first book we learn that the Jane brought five buttons back from Fillory.  One of her sisters hid them, but she found them again, and took one of the buttons for her personal use.  She still has it at the end of "The Magicians".

Penny obtains one of the buttons from the magic grey market.  He forms a party with himself, Quentin, Eliot and others to go to Fillory for the first time.  At the end of the book (as mentioned in the answer to [How did Quentin and the 3 others return to Fillory between The Magicians and The Magician King](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139794/how-did-quentin-and-the-3-others-return-to-fillory-between-the-magicians-and-the)) he goes off by himself leaving the button with the rest of the party.

In the second book Josh takes the initial button (since the others want to remain in Fillory) and goes exploring with it.  Later he sells it for $250M to a dragon.

Although Quentin switches between worlds five times in the second book, he never does so by means of a button.  In fact his (and Julia's) search for a button is one of the plot drivers for this book.  As far as I can tell once Josh has sold his button none of the main characters have one any more.

At the start of book three we have Eliot, Janet, Josh and Poppy in Fillory, and Quentin (with Plum) on Earth.  I would not expect anyone to have any buttons at this point, and indeed they go unmentioned until towards the end of this book.

But as the end approaches there seem to be at least three of them around.

1. Eliot returns by himself to Earth.  It does not say how he travelled, but it would appear that he used a button.  When Eliot and Plum try to travel to the Neitherlands they end up unexpectedly inside one of the buildings.

> (page 356) "This isn't right," Eliot said.  "This isn't the Neitherlands I don't think.  We've been hijacked.  Button-jacked."

The inference is that they were traveling by button.

2. Quentin and Alice travel to the Neitherlands separately soon after.  On arriving the narrator says

> (page 357) Sure enough, up popped Quentin and Alice, her spluttering and blowing, ... then swam breaststroke over to the steps, at which point it became apparent that she was completely naked.  What, did they roll over onto the button halfway through?

Again the inference is that they travelled by button.  It must have been a different button to the one used by Eliot and Plum.

3. Simultaneously Fillory is going to pieces.  Although Julia sends Janet, Josh and Poppy to the Neitherlands, it is apparent that they had a button.  Earlier Josh said:

> (page 328) "When it gets too bad," he said, "we'll come back for you.  With the button".

Since Eliot has already left at this point, Josh cannot have been talking about either of the buttons that Eliot presumably had with him.  So there must be a third button.

---

But I do not see how they can have any buttons.

1. It is hard to believe that the dragon would ever give up the one it bought.
2. I could believe that Jane would give up hers.  But when Eliot and Janet meet Jane earlier in the third book it is apparent that they have never met before.  The narration says nothing about her giving her button to them.
3. The other three buttons presumably vanished into hands of magic collectors on Earth.  Since the dragon was willing to pay $250M they must not change hands often or at all.  But in any case the narrative is clear that Quentin does not have a button and there seems to be no way that Eliot/Janet/Josh/Poppy could ever have got to Earth to look for one.

So how did they get the buttons?  Did I miss some text?  Or do we just have to assume that Eliot and co. found some cache of buttons in Fillory that the author did not bother to narrate.

(This question is about the books not the TV series)

Comment: It's not necessary 5 buttons. The number 5 comes from Plover's writings, who has this information second-hand. The first-hand information about the buttons does not specify a number, just a "Box of Buttons", which was promptly hidden - so only Jane and Helen knew how many button there were.